# Is kafka jdbc sink can create indexed table?

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have latency issue in my JDBC sink. When i run my JDBC sink with `insert.mode=upsert` it takes about 10 second for each message get in into SQL Server. My Supervisor advice to used indexed table which can reduce time in update time consumption. I'm still new use JDBC Sink and I want to ask if JDBC sink has ability to create an indexed table if not exist with `auto.create` option to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the sources JDBC Sink Connector [creates](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/74fad2d5683c0f5f77784dc4f3ac94fd10b6fa59/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/GenericDatabaseDialect.java#L1654-L1678) table with primary key only (no other indexes).

You can see [examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/42b74cb8aa89b18acdcbe559fecedc89f7ffb009/src/test/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/SqlServerDatabaseDialectTest.java#L126-L159) of `CREATE` statement fo SQL Server from unit tests.

Comment: this is a disadvantage for me as in case the number of row increased the performa are decreased if the index are not created

Comment: You can add index or create whole table with index manually

Comment: I have read that sql server syntax for upsert mode in jdbc sink are merge, as was as i use right now. I want to know the condition of the merge syntax is based from table PK or something else?